# How to access the content of externally added javascript file itself

Tags: javascript

This may be more of a hypothetical or a curiosity question but I believe there can be a practical use so please bear with me.

If I add a JavaScript file  as follows `<Script src='myscript.js'></script>` would there be a way to access the content myscript.js using JavaScript in a similar way as we access innHTML of a DIV element? This can be used in site that give online tutorial for HTML and JavaScript(similar functionality as the 'try it yourself' in w3school).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to make an AJAX request to the server for that file. That would return the file's contents, after which you can do what you like.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do

```
 var a = document.getElementsByTagName("Script");
```

and handle it the same as the divs etc... 
You will still need the Ajax call though if the script tag refers to a js file than inline JS